# How to check if a subdomain exists

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-8, subdomain, webclient

I am building a Windows Phone app and I need to check if a certain subdomain, like xyz.abcdefgh.com exists or not, but how to accomplish that? I tried the following code:

```
Try
Dim client As New WebClient
client.DownloadStringAsync(New Uri("http://www.thwa.suyashsrijan.com"))
Catch ex As Exception
Messagebox.show(ex.tostring)
End Try
```

but it doesn't work (no error is thrown even when the subdomain mentioned in code doesn't exist)

Any help will be very much appriciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DownloadStringAsync` is exactly that – asynchronous.
It only finishes some time after your code finishes running.

To see the result or error, handle the `DownloadStringCompleted` event.